# Python read text file based on partial name and file timestamp

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, timestamp

I'm trying to pull two of the same files into python in different dataframes, with the end goal of comparing what was added in the new file and removed from the old. So far, I've got code that looks like this:

```
In[1] path = r'\\Documents\FileList'
      files = os.listdir(path)

In[2] files_txt = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'txt']

In[3] for f in files_txt:
          data = pd.read_excel(path + r'\\' + f)
          df = df.append(data)
```

I've also set a variable to equal the current date minus a certain number of days, which I want to use to pull the file that has a date equal to that variable:

```
d7 = dt.datetime.today() - timedelta(7)
```

As of now, I'm unsure of how to do this, as the first part of the filename always remains the same but they add numbers at the end (eg. file_03232016 then file_03302016). I want to parse through the directory for the beginning part of the filename and add it to a dataframe if it matches the date parameter I set.

EDIT: I forgot to add that sometimes I also need to look at the system date created timestamp, as the text date in the file name isn't always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some modifications to your original code to get a list of files containing your target date.  You need to use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta

d7 = dt.datetime.today() - timedelta(7)
target_date_str = d7.strftime('_%m%d%Y')

files_txt = [f for f in files if f[-13:] == target_date_str + '.txt']

>>> target_date_str + '.txt'
'_03232016.txt'

data = []
for f in files_txt:
      data.append(pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path,  f))
df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This actually helps a ton, thank you!! I have one more question though; would you know how to work the files date created system timestamp into this? Sometimes the date appears in the filename and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Could you please give examples of actual filenames?

Comment: Sure; price_list_20150309025753.txt is one example. There are other files I have to pull in to the script that have a similar naming convention but with just the date rather than datetime, so the above code is definitely useful. Sometimes the price_list_ file won't have a datetime stamp or any date stamp on it at all, so being able to pull the system one as well if that isn't available would be helpful.

Comment: I assume you just want to filter on the date portion. If so, `[f for f in files if f[-4:] == '.txt' and f[-19:-10] == target_date]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `strftime` in order to represent your datetime variable as a string with desired format and `glob` for searching files by file mask in the directory:

```
import datetime as dt
import glob

fmask = r'\\Documents\FileList\*' + (dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(7)).strftime('%m%d%Y') + '*.txt'
files_txt = glob.glob(fmask)

# concatenate all CSV/txt files into one data frame
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files_txt], ignore_index=True)
```

PS I guess you want to use `read_csv` instead of `read_excel` when working with `txt` files unless you really have excel files with `txt` extension?

Comment: Was a mistake on my part. I use that same bit of code for a lot of excel files so I forgot to copy in read_csv rather than excel.