# Selecting files based on creation date

Tags: python

I have a folder named myclientcard and it has 69 subfolders in that subfolders we have number of subfolders where it has to go to error folder and inside error folder it has number of txt files, So I want the contents of those text file of all 69 folders inside error inside the specified using the date format `17/01/2019` to `24/01/2019` and convert it into excel file

```
import os
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os.path import join
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
mypath = "D:\myclientcard"
files = [join(mypath,f) for f in listdir(mypath) if '.txt' not in f]
for file in files:
    path = file
    filename =[join(path,f) for f in listdir(path) if 'ERROR' in f]
    #print(filename)
    for text_file_path in filename:
        file_path = text_file_path
        textfiles = [join(file_path,f) for f in listdir(file_path) if '.txt' in f]
        for files in textfiles:
                reading_files = open(files,'r')
                read = reading_files.read()
                writting_files = open('result.txt','a')
                wr = writting_files.write(read)
                read_files = pd.read_csv('result.txt',delim_whitespace='')
                writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
                read_files.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=false)
                writer.save()
                reading_files.close()
                writting_files.close()
```

Comment: ya sure ill send the code please wait

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932130/iterate-through-folders-then-subfolders-and-print-filenames-with-path-to-text-f). You requirement is mostly answered in the link provided.

Comment: @vmaroli sorry that is not meeting my constraint

Comment: @Venkatesh Garnepudi can u help me out to add a line of code where based on the date format the files to be extracted

Comment: if `filename`,`textfiles` is in order, everything can be done. How to order it? If there's any time stamp in file name , it can be done. Once check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36318986/6113743

Comment: @VenkateshGarnepudi i want to extract the data of the files based on the date it was created not the file name itself as 05-01-2019 not this file name , i want the file contents for which it was created on 05-01-2019.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date). Assuming you are on a windows platform.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os.path import join
# Importing datetime module
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
mypath = "D:\myclientcard"

# Add start date here
start_date = dt.strptime('17/01/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')
# Add end date here
end_date = dt.strptime('24/01/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')
files = [join(mypath,f) for f in listdir(mypath) if '.txt' not in f]
for file in files:
    path = file
    filename =[join(path,f) for f in listdir(path) if 'ERROR' in f]
    #print(filename)
    for text_file_path in filename:
        file_path = text_file_path
        textfiles = [join(file_path,f) for f in listdir(file_path) if '.txt' in f]
        # Filtering on the basis of date
        textfiles = [f for f in textfiles if ((os.path.getctime(f) >= start_date) and (os.path.getctime(f) <= end_date))]
        for files in textfiles:
                reading_files = open(files,'r')
                read = reading_files.read()
                writting_files = open('result.txt','a')
                wr = writting_files.write(read)
                read_files = pd.read_csv('result.txt',delim_whitespace='')
                writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
                read_files.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=false)
                writer.save()
                reading_files.close()
                writting_files.close()
```

On a side note, consider optimizing your code. Also try `os.walk`, it can be useful at times!

Comment: its pooing me an bug like this can u help me out  ,start_date = dt.strptime('17/01/2019', '%d/%m/%Y').total_seconds()
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Comment: Please accept the answer it this was what you were looking for.

Comment: its throwing me an error again can u please help me out.textfiles = [f for f in textfiles if ((os.path.getctime(f) - start_date) >= 0 and (os.path.getctime(f) - end_date) <= 0)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'